# How to remove unwanted node from a parsed graphql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

For example If I have some code like this:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const getUserMeta = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUserMeta($owner: String!) {
    getUserMeta(owner: $owner) {
      familyName
      givenName
      workAddress
      facebookUrl
      owner
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      careers {
        items {
          id
          company
          companyUrl
          showCompany
          owner
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
    }
  }
`;

const ast = gql(getUserMeta)


// for example if I want to remove the `showCompany` node
// I expect some method like this would work... but there is no such a method..
// ast.removeNodeByPath('GetUserMeta.careers.showCompany')

apolloClient.query(query:ast, variables: {limit: 100})
```

Comment: If you remove the field `showCompany` from the query then the value won't be returned in the output and you won't have to remove itl

Comment: https://lihautan.com/manipulating-ast-with-javascript/#targeting-a-node

Comment: just for people who like me, I created a tiny lib just for this https://github.com/yaquawa/partial-gql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/

The `graphql-js` library provides the function to manipulate the AST.

I recommend using the `visitor` function which is documented on that page.

Here is a snippet of code that use the visitor to add some stuff (just what I had as part of my product), it can give you a model to get started.

```
 let editedAst = visit(stage.graphQLDocument, {
  SelectionSet: {
    leave(node, key, parent, path, ancestors) {
      if (
        ancestors.length === 5 &&
        (ancestors[2] as OperationDefinitionNode).kind ===
          'OperationDefinition' &&
        (ancestors[3] as SelectionSetNode).kind === 'SelectionSet'
      ) {
        if (
          node.selections.find((s) => {
            return (s as FieldNode).name.value === CHUNK_ID;
          })
        ) {
          return undefined;
        }
        const fieldChunkId = {
          kind: 'Field',
          directives: [],
          name: { kind: 'Name', value: CHUNK_ID },
        };

        return {
          ...node,
          selections: [...node.selections, fieldChunkId],
        };
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just opened another question about the `visit` function, if you are interested  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167082/when-to-use-enter-leave-with-visit-function-of-graphql